# How to use python to tokenize and chunk tagged sentences line by line

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, tokenize

I'm a Linguistist and would want to use python to tokenize sentences in a csv document line by line and also tell the tag and the token position in the tag(B-beginning or I-inside) just like the example below.

```
"id", "sentence"
"1", "<person>Claire</person>lived in<location>London UK</location>for<time>2 years</time>"
"2", "<location>UK</location> is in<location>Europe</location>"
 ...........
 ...........


 dataframe = pd.read_csv(document)
 sentences = dataframe['sentence']
 for line in sentences :
     #print token position tag

 >> Claire  B-Per  person 
    lived   null   null   
    in      null   null
    London  B-Loc  location
    UK      I-Loc  location
    for     null   null
    2       B-Tim   time
    years   I-Tim   time 

    UK      B-Loc  location
    is      null   null                
    in      null   null
    Europe  B-Loc  location
```

Comment: Without knowing what's in your CSV file, this can't really be answered.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Its there. I wrote it in the first 3 lines: "id", "sentences"

Comment: @Juli, welcome to StackOverflow and NLP. Firstly, you would need some basic knowledge of programming language and some NLP experience for that. There is no silver bullet where linguist can easily get their desired output from a csv file or a textfile as yet. maybe you can start from this book: http://www.nltk.org/book/ .